# wordpress site uploaded on Plesk server gives warning and permalink issue

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, parallel-processing, plesk

I have uploaded my WordPress site to shared plesk parallel panel to dedicated plesk parallel panel. But now I am getting one warning in testimonial rotator plugin as follow :

```
Warning:  file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(PATH1\httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/SITE_URL/wp-admin/edit.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (PATH_2_SITE;PATH_2_TEMP)
```

And also having problem in permalink settings. As i set it to custom Structure like :

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

it gives 404 : page not found.

Don't know where is the problem actually, on server or in my site.

Because it was working fine on shared plesk. 
Please help me out of these issue

Thanks in Advance,

Mona

Comment: **Troubleshooting tip #1:** Deactivate all plugins, revert to Twenty Twelve, and see if you get the errors.

Comment: The host has applied security settings. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

Comment: Thanks for reply, I seen that thing  http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir but how to solve that i don't know. can we change that settings?

Comment: Amal Murali, I tried that but not working on new server of plesk. same thing was working in previous plesk

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are loading files from a second site located on the same server, is this correct?

You will need to adjust the open_basedir settings to allow the PHP functions to access the files in the other site which would ordinarily be outside of your allowed access.

I think you are indicating that this site is on a dedicated server (that I assume you have full access to), if so you should be able to create a vhost.conf file for the Wordpress site which would adjust the open_basedir settings for this site.

Something like:

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/site1.com/httpdocs/>
  php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/site1.com/httpdocs/:/var/www/vhosts/site2.com/httpdocs/:/tmp"
</Directory>
```

...should work